# Swift 2.0 - MigrationCall to error throwing function cannot be converted

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am migrating from Swift 1.0 to Swift 2.0. After automatic migration I have a lot of warnings and errors. I am trying to fix them. This is one of them fixed but I still have a warning.

> Warning "Migration. Call to an error throwing function cannot be
>   converted." on the row

```
let signedUsers = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [PMMUser]
```

Code of function:

```
func signedUser() -> PMMUser? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PMMUser")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "signed == true")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let signedUsers = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [PMMUser]
        if signedUsers.count == 0 {
            throw PMMUserError.NoSignedUser
        } else if signedUsers.count > 1 {
            throw PMMUserError.MoreThatOneUserSigned
        } else {
            return signedUsers.first
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```